# Blackberry - EventInjector to activate speaker

Tags: blackberry, speaker

I am trying to activate the speaker-phone for an incoming call. I am able to accept the incoming call programatically through the EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent, but I am not able to turn on the speaker-phone with the KeyCodeEvent.

I registered with Phone listener through the following method.

```
Phone.addPhoneListener(instance);
```

then I try to activate the speaker in the `callConnected` method as follows.

```
EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent speakerKeyDown = 
    new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN,
        (char) Keypad.KEY_SPEAKERPHONE, KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD);
EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent speakerKeyUp = 
    new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent.KEY_UP,
        (char) Keypad.KEY_SPEAKERPHONE, KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD);
EventInjector.invokeEvent(speakerKeyDown);
EventInjector.invokeEvent(speakerKeyUp);
```

Comment: What is actually happening when your KeyCodeEvent code executes?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your code within a thread and use Thread.sleep(100) between the invoking of the key just like that.

Might this will work

```
EventInjector.invokeEvent(speakerKeyDown);
Thread.sleep(100);
EventInjector.invokeEvent(speakerKeyUp);
Thread.sleep(100);
```

Comment: Its still not working. How ever after the introducing the above mentioned code **Mute** is activated instead of the Speaker phone.

Comment: Earlier at some times it used to activate the mute Key but now mute key is always activated.

Answer (score 0):

For activating loudspeaker you can use this code:

```
EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent speakerKeyDown =  new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN,(char)Keypad.key(2359296),KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD);
EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent speakerKeyUp   =  new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent.KEY_UP,(char)Keypad.key(2359296),KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD);
EventInjector.invokeEvent(speakerKeyDown);
try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception e){}
EventInjector.invokeEvent(speakerKeyUp);
```